# adding href to table link creates extra spacing?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a website and have run into the issue that every time I insert a href link into a table, it moves the text forward a few spaces. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>Title</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="site_title1">
    <h2><span>Title</span></h2>
</div>
<div id="site_title2">
        <h4><span>subtitle</span></h4>
</div>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li class="events"><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
        <li class="music"><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
</br>
<div id="tablelist">
    <p><a href="#Orchestral">Orchestral</a> | <a href="#Chamberensemble">Chamber            Ensemble</a> | <a href="#Solo">Solo</a> | <a href="#Choral">Choral</a> | <a href="#Electronic">Electronic</a> </p>
</div>

    <a name="Chamberensemble"></a>
        <h1>Chamber Ensemble</h1>
            <table border="1">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title/Year</th>
                        <th>Instrumentation</th>
                        <th>Length</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="linkinquestion.html">the link in question</a></td>
                        <td>Mezzo-soprano, Piano</td>
                        <td>15 minutes</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>this is not a link</td>
                        <td>Mezzo-soprano, Piano</td>
                        <td>15 minutes</td>
                    </tr>


</body>



<footer>
<p>Copyright 2014</p>
<br>
```

CSS:

```
    /* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}


/* main font style, background color, and body margins */

body{
    font-family: "Calibri", "Candara", "Segoe", "Segoe UI", "Optima", "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:black;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 75px 40px 20px 125px ;
            background-color: rgb(255,255,224);

}

/* main header style */

div#site_title1 
{
    font-size: 28px;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color:rgb(188,143,143);
}

div#site_title2
{
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color:rgb(188,143,143);
}

/*menu style*/

div#menu ul a
{
    color:black;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}

div#menu li
{   display: inline;
}

div#menu ul a:hover
{
    color:rgb(188,143,143);
}

div#menu
{word-spacing:5px; }


#menu, a {
padding: 20px;
}

/* about and image positioning */

div#about
{
    width:500px;
}

div#images
{
    float:right;
    margin-right: 475px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

/* event headers and text */

div#eventheader
{
    font-size: 18px;
    color:rgb(188,143,143);
    font-weight: bold;
}

div#eventsubheader
{
    font-size: 16px;
    color:#000;
    font-weight: bold;
}

div#eventtext
{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:black;
    width:400px;
}

/* table positioning/style */

th{
    width:250px;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}

td{
    width:250px;
    padding:1%;
}

div#tablelist{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#000;
}

table {
    margin-left: 25px;
}


/* misc. */


a {text-decoration: none;
    color:#000;
    }

a:hover {color:rgb(188,143,143);}


div#line{
    width:400px;
}


/* footer style */

footer {
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(188,143,143);
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
```

In addition, why is my footer above my table text? This isn't as important because it works fine in the actual code(with more things in it), but i'm just curious.

Thank you for taking the time to answer this!

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GBuN3/

Comment: This may not be related, but you have a rogue <tbody> tag in your table that looks out of place.

Comment: your HTML is not corect, many tag unclosed as tbody , table and <footer> is in between </body> & </html> , strange that you still see it :)  http://jsfiddle.net/GBuN3/20/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have applied padding to it. Your code says:

```
#menu, a { padding: 20px; }
```

The above affects **all** `a` elements, anywhere. If you were looking to apply padding only to `a` that are within `#menu`, you should use:

```
#menu, #menu a { padding: 20px; }
```

Updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GBuN3/4/

Answer (score 0):

So I literally deleted CSS from the CSS file until the problem went away.  Whatever I last deleted was the cause of the problem.  I found this:

```
#menu, a {
padding: 20px;
}
```

Like setek said, the **a** tag has padding of 20px, so that explains the 20px indent of your **a href** tag.